# How to return a value from a method with a generic return type and where clause

Tags: swift, generics, where-clause

I can make a function return a value with a generic return type but I can't make it return a value when I am using a `where clause` as well.

This is the code I am using:

```
func genericFunction<T: Collection>(collectionOne: T, collectionTwo: T) where T.Iterator.Element == (NSNumber) -> [Int] {


}
```

It compiles ok. But if I try and return this:

```
let array = [1]


return array
```

I get this error: 'unexpected non-void return type in void function' but as you can see the from the method declaration there is a return type so I have probably used the wrong syntax to declare the method.

What syntax should I use to return a value from the method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func genericFunction<T: Collection>(collectionOne: T, collectionTwo: T)
     where T.Iterator.Element == (NSNumber) -> [Int]
```

defines a function returning `Void`, with the constraint

```
T.Iterator.Element == (NSNumber) -> [Int]
```

i.e. the element type is restricted to be a `(NSNumber) -> [Int]` closure.

What you probably want is

```
func genericFunction<T: Collection>(collectionOne: T, collectionTwo: T) -> [Int]
    where T.Iterator.Element == (NSNumber)
```

which is a function returning `[Int]`, with the element type 
restricted to `NSNumber`.

In other words, the where-clause comes *after* the return type.